# Equivalence of category of cones

Tags: category-theory

If $ E \colon I \rightarrow J $ is an equivalence of categories and $ D \colon J \rightarrow C $ is a diagram of shape $ J $ in $ C $, is the category of cones over $ D $ equivalent to the category of cones over $ D \circ E $?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried doing this directly by sending a cone $ \lambda \colon c \rightarrow D $ from the constant functor from $ J $ at $ c $ to the cone $ \lambda E \colon c \rightarrow DE $ from the constant functor from $ I $ at $ c $ whose components are given by $ (\lambda E)_x = \lambda_{E(x)} $ with the obvious assignment to morphism, and doing the same thing in the other direction with a quasi-inverse $ E^{\prime} $  to $ E $, but I'm getting stuck because I want to say that $ \lambda E E' \cong \lambda $, but this seems like an abuse of notation...

Comment: You're right that this is an abuse of notation: when you interpret cones as natural transformations from constant functors, an isomorphism of cones is not an "isomorphism of natural transformations," which can't even be made meaningful in a 1-category. Rather, it's a natural isomorphism of the cones interpreted as *functors* out of a different category, which is the rub of my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary solution can be made to work, but let me suggest a slightly more sophisticated route. The first observation is that the category of cones over a diagram $D$ is the category of functors $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(J),C)_D$ from the cone category over $J$ to $C$ which restrict to $D$ along the inclusion $J\to \text{cone}(J)$. Here $\text{cone}(J)$ is just $J$ with a new initial object adjoined. It's straightforward to show that $E$ induces an equivalence between $\text{cone}(I)$ and $\text{cone}(J)$ (when extended to map the new initial objects to each other.) Thus the categories $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(I),C)$ and $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(J),C)$ of all cones over $I$-and $J$-shaped diagrams are equivalent, being functor categories out of equivalent categories. This equivalence sends a cone over $D$ to the corresponding cone over $D\circ E$, so restricts to an equivalence of $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(J),C)_D$ with $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(I),C)_{D\circ E}$

This is still a bit of a mouthful, so a yet more sophisticated and shorter proof would interpret $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(J),C)_D$ using a touch of 2-category theory. Briefly, $\text{cone}(J)$ is a pushout in the 2-category of categories and similarly $\text{Func}(\text{cone}(J),C)_D$ is an equalizer, so the 2-categorical analogue of the fact that limits and colimits of isomorphic diagrams are isomorphic implies that the two cone categories are equivalent.

Comment: This is a really great explanation! Thanks!

Comment: I think you need a bit more than "a touch of 2-category theory" to know that limits and colimits of equivalent diagrams are equivalent – you have to talk about either pseudo(co)limits or (co)fibrancy of diagrams.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for the comment. To be sure I caught your second idea, is this about homotopy (co)limits in the canonical model structure on Cat, or something I can do in other 2-categories as well?

Comment: Yes, I mean the canonical model structure on $\mathbf{Cat}$. Whereas the business with pseudo(co)limits applies in arbitrary 2-categories.